# Nested ng-repeat issue with api call

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue not seeing the second `ng-repeat` fields. The first `ng-repeat` fires no problem and the console log of `$scope.fields` is getting back the correct data, but the input boxes don't seem to be populating on the page.

I seem to be able to get the data correctly, I just don't seem to be able to get the hang of the nested `ng-repeat` section.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                <div id="categories_inputs" ng-repeat="category in categories">

                    <h2>{{category.name + ' - ' + category.templateCategoryId}}</h2><br>

                    <div id="field_inputs" ng-repeat="field in fields">

                    Field: <input ng-value="field.field" />
                    Label: <input ng-value="field.label" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is js

```
    api.getCategories({templateId: template}, function(categories){
        $scope.categories = categories;

        angular.forEach(categories, function(value, key){
            api.getTemplateFields({templateCategoryId: value.templateCategoryId}, function(fields) {
                $scope.fields = fields;
            });
        });


   });
```

Comment: I think this kind of problem relates to object reference. You can try to nest `fields` with another JSON object.

Comment: Replace `ng-value` with `ng-model`

Comment: @tymeJV That did not work. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Now that I read this closer - your `fields` variable is going to be overwritten each time the API call returns, is that intended?

Comment: @tymeJV Definitely not, I see what you're saying though. I need to send the html the data from fields and run it through the repeat. How can I do this?

Comment: No. You need to store the fields of a category in the category. Not in the scope. Then iterate over category.fields. You should also learn to use promises instead of passing callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with changing the js to:

```
$scope.categoryLoaded = function(category){
    api.getTemplateFields({templateCategoryId: category.templateCategoryId}, function(fields) {
        alert(category.templateCategoryId);
        category.fields = fields;
    });
};
```

and the html is now

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-init="categoryLoaded(category)">

                <h2>{{category.name + ' - ' + category.templateCategoryId}}</h2><br>

                <div ng-repeat="field in category.fields">
                Field: <input ng-value="field.field" />
                Label: <input ng-value="field.label" />

                </div>
            </div>
```